# mongo engine update command for fields which has a proper input value

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have scenario where  i have to update many records. but the problem is i have to update those fields which have some variable coming as input. if any incoming field has none then it should not overwrite its existing db values.

```
new_code = None
new_type = "new values"

user.objects(query).update(set__type=new_type ,set__code=new_code)
```

above query return 10 records but i want to update only type coz it has a value. but code value should not be upated in db. coz its variable is none ( coming from user input form )

i have to make some kind of if else condition

in db i have records like
type=old,code=111
as new_code is not coming as input so it should update only type and db should look like
type = new values , code = 111

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean the user input before updating - None is valid datatype and value to store.

As these are just kwargs you could build a dictionary of what you want to update:

```
update = {}
if new_type:
    update['set__new_type' = new_type
if new_code:
    update['set__new_code' = new_code

user.objects(query).update(**update)
```